# Ruby backtick'd code exits with 136?

Tags: ruby, shell

I have a ruby script that executes another ruby script via backticks. Like this:

```
output = `#{name}/#{sccript} --list`
```

In certain scenarios (I'm running this during build time of a binary package and there are multiple instances of same script running) this will fail.

output is 0 lenght and `$?` is set to 136.

Any ideas what would be causing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Exit code](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/BFROOT/www/Computing/Environment/Tools/Batch/exitcode.html) 136 is in the range 129-255, which represent jobs terminated by Unix signals.

To find out which signal, subtract 128, and you find its signal 8: [`SIGFPE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGFPE). One possible cause might be integer division by zero in a C program.

Comment: Actually the app im calling is also a ruby script. What makes this hard to debug is that this is only preproduceable for me when im calling this script when im building a debian package with dpkg-buildpackage and i have parallel execution via make -j4.  Directly called and/or without concurrency it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

backticks will always return whatever the stdout of the call will be, if you just want true or false, use system:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :009 > \`echo "hello"\`
=> "hello\n"   
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :010 > system("echo 'hello'")   
hello 
=> true
```

so, to answer your question '136' is whatever your script is returning

Comment: You're giving an answer about the text output, but he's reporting that the exit code (`$?`) is 136.

Comment: useful (to me at least) answer anyway.